# Meaning of a continuous function taking [0,1] "into itself "

Tags: real-analysis

I've got a question involving the statement "Let $ f $ be a continuous function of  $[0, 1] $ into itself". I have not been taught all the terminology and would appreciate if anyone could tell me what the "into itself" part means.

Answer (score 2):

It means that it is a function from $[0,1]$ into $[0,1]$.

Comment: Thank you. Does that mean that f(x)=x on [0,1], or just f(x) is an element of [0,1] for all x being an element of [0,1] ?

Comment: It means that for all $x$ in $[0,1]$, $f(x)$ is an element of $[0,1]$.

Comment: "Continuous  " is irrelevant here,  if that also is a concern.

Comment: @dmtri That's why I did not use that word in my answer.

Comment: @Jose,  sorry this comment was supposed to go under OP's question.